# choose array to act on in function without a version of function for each copy of array

Tags: c++, arrays, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to apply a minimax type algorithm to a Reversi/Othello type game - the problem i'm finding is that each 1/2 ply will needs its' own "fake" game-board to test on.

Thus it appears, as arrays cannot be passed as parameters, that I either need a function with 64 parameters and an array for each 1/2 ply, or I need to hand code copies of the functions and arrays for each ply (i.e. checkMovePly1, checkMovePly2, etc.), or create the arrays locally (at which point the AI taking a move will result in the generation and creation of 64^(2*ply) arrays every turn, which seems like it could run somewhat slowly).

If I can solve the array problem, this seems like it should work for a few ply, as it will only be a time complexity of O(64^(2*ply)), though depending on method that may be 64^(2*ply) creations and destructions of arrays.

Any idea how to get around the multiple array issue, is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: I tried to answer, but I'm not sure if I fully understood your question.

Comment: Who has told you arrays can't passed as parameters?

Comment: and your chosen tags for this question aren't good at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

C++ provides various containers that should be preferred to arrays. In this case, I would suggest an `std::array`. If you don't have `std::array`, an `std::vector` will also work.

```
void foobar(std::array<int, 64> board);
```

This function will copy the array passed in by value.

Answer (score 0):

First arrays can be passed as parameters, but the function called will be operating directly on the original array, not its own copy (beware).

```
void foo(int[8][8] board);
```

Second, standard (or custom if need be) container classes are safer to use and easier to copy when needed.  Native arrays don't copy easily without slightly hackish tricks, at which point using container classes should render your code easier to read anyway.

Third, this problem looks like a classic subject for a recursive algorithm, which could allow all work to be done on the same array (or container class) instance, thus keeping your resource requirements O(1): fixed gameboad size and known maximum resursion depth.